# Check is exit of object in s3 with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I want to upload object to s3 if object is not modified or new object using boto3
how can i check given file is new/modified

```
isNewObject(bucket, key, file)

    s3hash = bucket.getHash(key)
    filehash = getHash(key)

    if (s3hash != filehash)
        return True
    else
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help, assuming your file data is in `data` and your hash in `digest`

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    obj = s3.Object('your-bucket', 'your-file')
    metadata = {}

    try:
            metadata = obj.metadata
    except:
            pass

    if 'md5' not in metadata or metadata['md5'] != digest:
            obj.put(Body = data, Metadata = { 'md5' : digest })
```